# Android camera error Failure delivering result ResultInfo

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to get my camera to work for my android app but i keep getting the following error

> 02-07 22:30:48.217 13197-13197/com.example.romsm.lap E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/8557 (has
>   extras) }} to activity
>   {com.example.romsm.lap/com.example.romsm.lap.TreeQuestionsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3510)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3553)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:165)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1374)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
>                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I have tried everything i can find online but nothing seems to fix it.
This is my code where I do the camera stuff.

```
btnPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                   // File file = new File(...);
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA);
                   // takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                }
            }
        });



    }
```

and

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA) {
            if (data != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to file
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            } else {
                // User cancelled the image capture or
                // image capture failed, advise user

            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Try out `Uri capturedImageUri = data.getData();`

Comment: why you need   `Bundle extras = data.getExtras();` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe i was fallowing a tutorial and thats what they used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code to make the camera works. You may try this.

```
 private void activeTakePhoto() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {

                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                //to generate random file name
                String fileName = "tempimg.jpg";

                try {
                    photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                    //captured image set in imageview
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you , i finally got it to work right. much appreciated